# Building a VPN that assigns local IP to each device

Tags: vpn, nat

I am trying to build a VPN, both site-to-site and point-to-site. I need the network to give each device a unique IP (doesn't have to be static) to identify them. Namely, if there are three devices in the main office, two in the branch office, one working from home, they would all have IP addresses 10.0.0.X. If a server in the main site receives a packet, it would be able to tell which specific device from the branch office sent it based on the network layer info alone.

For example, I am now looking at a doc from OpenVPN on building site-to-site VPN: https://openvpn.net/vpn-server-resources/site-to-site-routing-explained-in-detail/  This is a good example of what I do NOT want. When a server on the main site receives a packet, it would seem like it originated from the VPN access server (and it did), while I would like the packet to have the IP address of the original sender.

My question is:
1.Is it possible, technically?
2.Is it possible with a software solution, or do I need specific hardware? I cannot simply use a Cisco device for some reasons. If such a device exist, what's the terminology for it so I can search for other vendors' products?

(I am aware it is possible to tell the sender's identity even with the IP NATed if I just do it from application layer. I have my reasons to not do that.)

(If I wrote anything that makes me sound like an idiot, that's because I'm not a network engineer. I am sorry for any mistake I made. My boss is not very reasonal and I cannot just tell him to halt the project till he hires an expert.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, what you are looking for is possible. You need a bridge VPN for that: By using a network bridge between your main office and your VPN, every network client sending out a DHCP request would receive an IP from your main dhcp server (which is serving the 10.0.0.X network). That way, all three networks are linked together, and you can reach all three locations without having to mess around with routing.

Check out openvpn's site on [ethernet bridging](https://openvpn.net/community-resources/ethernet-bridging/).

And you do not need specific hardware for that - except that the VPN tunnel endpoint needs to run on a network capable device plugged into the correct network. (which can be very small: a Raspberry Pi is more than enough for such a task) OpenVPN compatible VPN solutions exists in software, and is included in many firewalls.

Comment: Is indeed what I was looking for, thank you! I will do some research on how to set up a bridge vpn.

Answer (score 0):

[Implement IPv6](https://blog.apnic.net/2017/06/09/using-openvpn-ipv6/), which allows this to be done without NATs, bridges, or DHCP.

Route `/64` subnets to the OpenVPN server, for the pools. IPs assigned out of these will be globally unique. Persist IPs and put them in DNS.

If client `2001:0db8:ee00:abcd::1247` sends a packet somewhere, that will be the source address wherever the packet goes. As from the tunnel server to the destination is just routing.

Note that due to the lack of NAT, end to end connectivity of IPv6 means devices all have their own IPs. Even without a VPN, over the internet. However, a VPN may still be desirable to enforce network configuration, or to add encryption.

Comment: I'm not sure it'll work. The way I understand it, while the usual VPN is considered in "routing mode", it isn't actually routing, but consuming the packet, encrypting the content, and sending it from itself. IPv6 is a good idea though and can solve my specific demand without even using VPN. I have already tought of it but the company computer comes with security software that straight up bans IPv6. So it wouldn't really matter if it works or not.

Comment: Removing VPN, and hardening the applications with encryption and identity awareness is better. "Zero trust" that doesn't rely on control of a perimeter. You didn't seem ready for it as you selected OpenVPN and wanted to identify by IP alone.  I have a low opinion of security products that disable IPv6. A proper IPv6 implementation is less work and more secure.

Comment: Indeed we are using application layer security measures beyond ip filtering. Blocking the access on the network layer just makes our services invisible to nmap scans. I agree with what you said about IPv6 though, but I didn't write that security platform myself.

Answer (score -1):

Bridge solution depicted in the accepted answer is way cumbersome and difficult to set up.
You can merely use the [proxy arp technique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_ARP).

I can even say that the OpenVPN effectively spoils VPN ecosystems since it gives a corrupted understanding of how real VPN setups should looke like, since it's a software router (instead of being just a VPN implementation).

Comment: OpenVPN *is* the way VPNs should be built. Easy to set up, easy to secure, easy to extend, widest support out there, no problems with virtually any network infrastructure. Just excellent. Much better that those cursed IPsec-based, L2TP-based, SSTP-based, GRE-based approaches, each of them just fails to work even in the presence of simple NAT and requires quirks in the configuration of both VPN and firewall just to get it working. Only one quite specific case, full mesh multipoint with dynamic routing, could give more points to DMVPN and only to it. In all other cases OpenVPN simply wins.

Comment: Yeah, sure. Another one of cargo-cultists failed at network constructing. Good luck, you will definitely need it, easy mode addict.